# CMD in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a simple vb script to automate shutdown in windows.

the code I am using is :

```
Dim ti
ti=InputBox("enter time in minutes")
ti=ti*60
Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd shutdown /s /t "& ti & " "
```

but when I enter the time and press enter , all I get is an command prompt window and nothing happens

I even tried by setting a default value for time and specifing the complete path for shutdown.exe ,but nothing seems to be working

```
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Command = "C:\Windows\System32 shutdown.exe -s -t 600 "
  WshShell.Run Command
```

can u please correct me and guide me towards the right code ....

Comment: `cmd` doesn't take parameters like that.  See `cmd /?` for usage.

Comment: when i use the full path and default value the folder C:\windows\System32 opens and nothing happens .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a backslash in your path:

```
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Command = "C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s -t 600 "
  WshShell.Run Command
```

Comment: thanks @Derek Tomes ,the above is working when full path is specified , but nothing happens when tried to execute from cmd .can you find what i am missing in there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run commands in `cmd` you have to use either `/k` (keep `cmd` window open after command finishes) or `/c` (close `cmd` window after command finishes). Here's the canonical way to do this:

```
ti = InputBox("enter time in minutes")
ti = ti * 60
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c shutdown -s -t " & ti
```

`%COMSPEC%` is a system environment variable with the path to `cmd.exe`.